# GWT/java and javascript

Tags: gwt

can i design my web pages in html and css instead of java methods and use gwt only in parts of page that i need ajax? and which one is better gwt, extgwt, vaadin(it run apps in server-side.can i also use it in client-side?), etc...? do i also need to know javascript for using gwt?
thanks

Comment: There are just so many questions, can you ask them one at a time?

Comment: Have you looked at UiBinder? That should help you decide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i design my web pages in html and
>   css instead of java methods and use
>   gwt only in parts of page that i need
>   ajax?

Yes, you can. You can create a div on your HTML page and insert your GWT widget there.

> which one is better gwt, extgwt,
>   vaadin(it run apps in server-side.can
>   i also use it in client-side?)

I don't know about vaadin but Ext-GWT is a set of ready made components to use with GWT which make your life easier especially if you want to build an web app that looks and feels like a desktop application.

> do i also need to know javascript for
>   using gwt?

No, it can be useful sometimes but is not necessary.